# How to fetch data with React Query?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-query

I'm building a Pokedex (Pokemon Index) application, using React Hook Form and React Query in which a user can submit a pokemon's name and that pokemon's data will render. I'm having trouble retrieving the individual pokemon's data. When I submit a pokemon's name, I receive a status 200 for the query, but the console prints an empty object. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

https://codesandbox.io/s/pokedex-5j1jf?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

useQuery hook expects a function that returns a promise. So handlePokemonFetch should look like this:

```js
const handlePokemonFetch = () => {
    return axios(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${query}`);
};
```

Normally react-query would run the query when the component is mounted. If you do not want this behaviour, you have to disable the query by setting, `enabled: false`, which you actually did. If you want to trigger a fetch by yourself react-query gives you `refetch` function:

```js
  //notice that we also destructure the refetch function
  const { isLoading, isError, data, error, refetch } = useQuery(
    "pokemon",
    handlePokemonFetch,
    {
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      enabled: false
    }
  );
 
  //when the data is available save it on the state  
  if(data) setPokemonCharacter(data);
```

And the you call that function when the form is submitted:

```js
<form onSubmit={()=>refetch()}>
```